# Why "quod" and not "quo" is used here?

Tags: grammar-identification, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata, pronouns, case, relative-pronouns

In chapter XXII of *Lingua latina per se illustrata: Colloquia Personarum*, I have read the following sentence (emphasis mine in the word I find difficult to understand):

> Hic anulus ex auro puro factus est, anulus tuus ex ferro, **quod** tenui auro operitur.

I don't understand why the relative pronoun **quod** is in nominative or accusative case. I think it should be in ablative case, since it refers to *ferro*, so it should be *quo*. Am I right? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A relative pronoun agrees with its antecedent in **gender** and **number**. Its case is determined by its role in the relative clause.

In this case, *quod* agrees with *ferrum* in gender (neuter) and number (singular). In the relative clause, though, it functions as the **subject**, so it's in the nominative case. Here's a possible translation:

> This ring was made from pure gold; your ring [was made] from iron, which is covered with thin gold [i.e. a thin layer of gold].

To understand why *quod* isn't ablative, you could try recasting the relative clause, substituting *ferrum* for the relative pronoun:

> **ferrum** tenui auro operitur.

> **The iron** is covered with thin gold.